# 404 thrown when trying to access file manager

Tags: control-panel, file-uploads, file-manager

On an EE 2.7.3 we are seeing a strange behaviour on the live server where we get a 404 when trying to access the file manager from Content > Files > File Manager.

We have the admin.php file renamed so the URL is this:

> /cms.php?S=0&D=cp&C=content_files

When we hit that URL, we get this:

[image]

I've no idea why as it's fine on the test and development environments and we've never seen this kind of error before.

Edit:

We also get this on other URLS such as Channel Admin:

> cms.php?S=0&D=cp&C=admin_content&M=channel_management

Comment: It looks like the classes haven't loaded as the 404 method is being called from line 271 of CodeIgniter.php.

Comment: Hi Russ - having the same issue. What did you do to fix it?

Comment: Hi @segovius. Re-uploading all the system files cured it, it seems FTP somehow caused an issue.